# C cipher table assign

Tags: c

How can I make a cipher table that convert an `int` to a `char`?

I already make a cipher table for encrypting like down below.

```
int ciper[]={
  ['h']=11, ['e']=12, ['l']=13, ['o']=14, 
};

int decript[]={
  ['11']=a,
};
```

How can I make the cipher table for decrypting?
The code reads from a file the string `hello` and cript message to another file `1112131314`

I want to make now a decript for this i need a decripting table
['11']=h .. to decript 1112131314 = hello`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

int encryption_data[] = {
    //-------------------------start alphabet lower and  upper case--------------------------------------------
    ['a'] = 11, ['b'] = 17, ['c'] = 23, ['d'] = 29, ['e'] = 35, ['f'] = 41, ['g'] = 47, ['h'] = 53, ['i'] = 58,
    ['j'] = 12, ['k'] = 18, ['l'] = 24, ['m'] = 30, ['n'] = 36, ['o'] = 42, ['p'] = 48, ['q'] = 54, ['r'] = 59,
    ['s'] = 13, ['t'] = 19, ['u'] = 25, ['v'] = 31, ['w'] = 37, ['x'] = 43, ['y'] = 49, ['z'] = 55, ['A'] = 60,
    ['B'] = 14, ['C'] = 20, ['D'] = 26, ['E'] = 32, ['F'] = 38, ['G'] = 44, ['H'] = 50, ['I'] = 56, ['J'] = 61,
    ['K'] = 15, ['L'] = 21, ['M'] = 27, ['N'] = 33, ['O'] = 39, ['P'] = 45, ['Q'] = 51, ['R'] = 57, ['S'] = 62,
    ['T'] = 16, ['U'] = 22, ['V'] = 28, ['W'] = 34, ['X'] = 40, ['Y'] = 46, ['Z'] = 52, 
    //diacritics here------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //-------------------------end alphabet lower and upper case-----------------------------------------------
    //---------------------------------------------start symbols-----------------------------------------------
    ['!'] = 63, ['@'] = 67, ['#'] = 71, ['$'] = 75, ['%'] = 78, ['^'] = 81, ['&'] = 84, ['*'] = 87, ['('] = 90,
    [')'] = 64, ['_'] = 68, ['+'] = 72, ['-'] = 76, [':'] = 79, ['='] = 82, ['['] = 85, [']'] = 88, ['{'] = 91,
    ['}'] = 65, ['\\'] = 69, ['|'] = 73, [';'] = 77, ['<'] = 80, ['>'] = 83, [','] = 86, ['.'] = 89, ['?'] = 92,
    ['/'] = 66, ['"'] = 70, ['\''] = 74, ['`'] = 402, ['~'] = 403, [' '] = 404, 
    //---------------------------------------------end symbols--------------------------------------------------
};

char decryption_data[]= {
    //-------------------------start alphabet lower and  upper case--------------------------------------------
    ["11"]='a',
};

void crypt_key()
{
    FILE *fin = fopen("sursa.txt","r");
    assert(fin != NULL);
    FILE *fout = fopen("rezultat.txt","w");
    assert(fout != NULL);
    for (int c; (c = getc(fin)) != EOF;) {
        if (c == '\n') {
            if (fputc('\n', fout) == EOF) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error writing to file fout with fputc\n");
                getchar();
            }
            continue;
        }
        if (fprintf(fout, "%5d ", encryption_data[c]) < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error writing to file fout with fprintf\n");
            getchar();
        }
    }
    fclose(fin);
    fclose(fout);
}

void decrypt_key()
{
    FILE *fin = fopen("rezultat.txt","r");
    assert(fin != NULL);
    FILE *fout = fopen("decrypted.txt","w");
    assert(fout != NULL);
    for (int c; (c = getc(fin)) != EOF;) {
        if (c == '\n') {
            if (fputc('\n', fout) == EOF) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error writing to file fout with fputc\n");
                getchar();
            }
            continue;
        }
        if (fprintf(fout, "%5c ", decryption_data[c]) < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error writing to file fout with fprintf\n");
            getchar();
        }
    }
    fclose(fin);
    fclose(fout);
}

void main()
{
    int x;
    printf("1 - Encryption\n");
    printf("2 - Decryption\n");
    printf("Option = ");
    scanf("%d", &x);
    switch(x)
    {
        case 1:
            if ( x == 1 )
            {
                crypt_key();
            }
            printf("Encryption done - check rezultat.txt\n");
            break;
        case 2:
            if ( x == 2 )
            {
               decrypt_key();
            }
            break;
        default: 
            printf("This option does not exist!\n");
            break;
    }
}
```

`Program should encrypt from file print output and decrypt from file with output put output doesnt work`

Comment: It is not clear what are the requirements for the decryption. First of all an integer has a far wider range than a character. Then, `'11'` is not an integer. That's not even a string because of single quotes instead of double quotes.

Comment: i want to assign a char to an int and i want to do this in a ciper table but i don`t know what data should i have to use

Comment: Could you please provide an example showing how en encrypted output would appear? For example: encrypt the string "Hello", list the conversion table for the required characters and show how the output would appear: would it be a binary sequence of integers? Would it be a sequence of integers in string form?

Comment: I posted an answer but in the meantime you changed your question. I believe it can still be helpful even if my short example doesn't match your full conversion table, but let me know.

Comment: `[11] = 'a'` etc. for the decryption data

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
int decript[]={
  ['11']=a,
};
```

to

```
int decript[]={
  [11]='a',
};
```

---

Based on the code, you output encrypted data using `fprintf` with a format of `"%5d "`.  You will need to use a complementary `fscanf` with a format of `"%5d "` or just `"%d"`, instead of the current `getc`, in order to read the encrypted data in.

Comment: if i let the structure with int the output is nothing null if i put char decript.. output is a unknown symbol

Comment: you will have to paste portions of your C code into the question...

Answer (score 0):

What you ask in the question, the `["11"]='a'` initializer,  is something similar to *associative arrays*, that unfortunately are not available in C language.

There are many ways to create conversion tables, and some of them involve structured programming (that is the definition of arrays of conversion structures.

---

Let's abstract from the definition of these arrays, and let's say that you are able to retrieve correctly the integers from your source, and if they are in string form you made sure they were all the same length (i.e. all with the same number of digits). With these assumptions the more general way to perform the conversion is using the **`switch-case`** statement:

Encrypt:

```
int encrypt;

switch (inputChar)
{
    case 'a':
        encrypt = 77;
        break;

    case 'e':
        encrypt = 12;
        break;

    case 'h':
        encrypt = 11;
        break;

    case 'l':
        encrypt = 13;
        break;

    case 'o':
        encrypt = 14;
        break;

    /*  ...  */

    default:
        /* Raise an error in case of unmanaged input char*/
}
```

Decrypt:

```
char decryptedChar;

switch (inputInt)
{
    case 77:
        decryptedChar = 'a';
        break;

    case 12:
        decryptedChar = 'e';
        break;

    case 11:
        decryptedChar = `h`;
        break;

    case 13:
        decryptedChar = 'l';
        break;

    case 14:
        decryptedChar = 'o';
        break;

    /*  ...  */

    default:
        /* Raise an error in case of unmanaged input int*/
}
```

Comment: No, sorry. I cannot write the whole conversion from my phone. My purpose was rather providing an example that you will be easily able to extend to your needs.

Comment: @RobertoCaboni simple "associative arrays" as posted by OP are legal since at least C99.  See http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#6.7.8p6 for details.

Comment: @rtx13 _"the expression shall be an integer constant expression"_, so something like `["11"]` would be invalid. When I wrote it the question was different.  But if you misunderstood my sentence it means it wasn't clear. I'll remove it. (And probably I'll remove the answer as well)

Comment: @RobertoCaboni you're right at least one location in the code has a string for the index.  I only saw the `['11']=a` which I suggested to OP should be `[11]='a'`.  I think your answer is valid.